# issue with writing ternary if else statement

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The following is my view razor syntax.

I am trying to check if the value is `m3` than `superscript 3` else shows normal value.

```
  <td width="20%">Volume((@Model.Volume == "m3") ? <span>m<sup>3</sup></span> : @Model.Volume)</td>
```

The actual output is `<td width="20%">Volume<br />((m3 == "m3") ? m3 : m3)'`

```
I am expecting <td width="20%">Fluid Volume<br />(m3)
```

Probably, i am not writing correct if else shorthand. Anyone can sport error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code block you have the `@` symbol in the wrong place and the correct syntax for a code block is

```
@(Model.Volume == "m3" ? someValue : Model.Volume)
```

However your wanting `someValue` to be html/text which you would normally do using

```
@:<span>m<sup>3</sup></span>
```

but this will confuse the compiler because of the `:` symbol which follows it.

Instead, you will need to use `Html.Raw()` to generate the output

```
<td width="20%">Volume (@Html.Raw(Model.Volume == "m3" ? "<span>m<sup>3</sup></span>" : Model.Volume))</td>
```

Comment: Excellent , i was missing usage of @Html.Raw. thanks you